# Send data from Arduino to asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arduino, unity-container

I have a problem regarding variable calling from C# to javascript in asp.net:
how to perform real-time retrieval of Arduino uno without wifi shield through C#, then passed to the javascript that will be displayed on the web, where the transmitted data equals 0 and 1 continuously.

**Example**

Arduino code:

```
void setup ( ) {
  / / Initialize the digital pin as an output .

}

void loop ( ) {
  Serial.write ( " 1 " ) ;
  delay (1000 ) ;
 Serial.write ( " 0 " ) ;
  delay (1000 ) ;
}
```

C# Code:

```
public String msg ;
public void DataReceivedHandler ( object sender , SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e ) {
    SerialPort sp = ( SerialPort ) sender ;
    indata string = sp.ReadExisting ( ) ;
    msg = indata ;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
SaySomethingToUnity function ( ) {
    a = < % = msg % >
    alert ( a) ;
    u.getUnity ( ) . SendMessage ( " Main Camera " , " note_c " , a) ;
}
```

Comment: i dont know what you're asking

Comment: I want to send data from Arduino to asp.net in realtime, do you know?